# ngx-toastr not showing up on first click or Ui not updating in angular 5 Digest cycle using google map apis

Tags: angular, google-maps, npm, angular5, google-geocoder

I'm using `ngx-toastr` in my Angular 5 projects. I have user form through which I'm taking LAT and LNG for user reverse geocoding. This is the applied condition in my code.

If city not found then it should show `toastr` message but this `toastr` message does not show up on the first click when I pressed submit button but when I click the second time it showed up. What could be the reason of this behavior?

Here is my code:

```
saveProfile() {
  this.getGeoLocation(this.latitude, this.longitude, (val) => {
    console.log(val)
    l
    if (!val) {
      console.log('val is null')
      this.toastr.error('Latitude  , Logitude is not valid', 'Error')
      return;
    }
    ...
  })
}
```

Here is my geocoding function:

```
getGeoLocation(lat: number, lng: number, cb) {
  let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  let latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

  let request = {
    latLng: latlng
  };
  geocoder.geocode(request, (results, status) => {
    console.log(results)
    if (results.length == 0) {
      cb(null)
    }

    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

      let result = results[0];
      console.log(result)
      let rsltAdrComponent = result.address_components;
      for (let ac = 0; ac < rsltAdrComponent.length; ac++) {
        let component = rsltAdrComponent[ac];
        switch (component.types[0]) {
          case 'locality':
            this.cityName = component.long_name;
            break;
        }
      };
      if (result != null) {
        cb(this.cityName);

      } else {
        cb(null);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting for example empty string as a result from Google API? `"" == null` is `false` in JS. Btw. You don't use strict equality operator (`===`) which could cause unexpected results during comparison.

Comment: I think its async issue @magos

Comment: Okay, but only toaster does not show up or whole method is not invoked? Could you please show us how you're calling `saveProfile()` in template?

Comment: I am calling it through UI submit button in reactive form @magos

Comment: toastr invoked on second click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im using google maps apis which are running outside scope of angular . So it was issue of angular zone. I have used zone run function for this

```
this.ngZone.run(() => {
  this.toastr.warning('This latitude and longitude is not found in selected city! fill 
 the correct one')
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install @angular/animations --save
```

```
import { ToastrModule, ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

imports: [
  BrowserAnimationsModule,
  ToastrModule.forRoot(),
],
```

Instead of using only `ToastrModule` you should use both animation and `ToastrModule`.